# exit after echo if command fails _always_ exiting

Tags: bash

I have a bash script setup where I `eval` a variable called `snake` and exit if there was an error. Even though there is no error upon executing the snake command, the `aws s3` commands below are not executed.

if I removed `|| echo "ERROR OCCURED, LOOK ABOVE. EXITING" ; exit 1`, then the aws commands will execute.

I know there isn't an error upon `eval $snake` because `echo "ERROR OCCURED, LOOK ABOVE. EXITING"` isn't returned to standard out (it only is when there is actually an error).

I need the aws commands to execute after successfully running `eval $snake`, but I'm unsure of how to do this.

```
s3='ebio/'

# do not edit contents below unless needed

snake="snakemake --default-remote-provider S3 --default-remote-prefix '$s3' --use-conda --cores 32 --rerun-incomplete --printshellcmds"

read -p "Rewrite over samples.tsv, peak_norm.tsv, and treated_vs_untreated.tsv files? (y/n)" -n 1 -r

if [[ $REPLY =~ ^[Yy]$ ]]
then        

# exit if snake fails

eval $snake || echo "ERROR OCCURED, LOOK ABOVE. EXITING" ; exit 1
    
# remove temp files
        
aws s3 rm --recursive s3://"$s3"rep_element_pipeline --exclude "*" --include "*tmp"
aws s3 rm --recursive s3://"$s3"rep_element_pipeline --exclude "*" --include "*sam.parsed"
aws s3 rm --recursive s3://"$s3"rep_element_pipeline --exclude "*" --include "*sam.parsed.done"
aws s3 rm --recursive s3://"$s3"rep_element_pipeline --exclude "*" --include "*.sam.tmp.combined_w_uniquemap.rmDup.sam"
aws s3 rm --recursive s3://"$s3"rep_element_pipeline --exclude "*" --include "*.sam.tmp.combined_w_uniquemap.prermDup.sam"
aws s3 rm --recursive s3://"$s3"rep_element_pipeline --exclude "*" --include "*.adapterTrim.round2.rmRep.bam.tmp"
aws s3 rm --recursive s3://"$s3"rep_element_pipeline --exclude "*" --include "*.fastq.gz.mapped_vs_bt2_hg38.sam"
aws s3 rm --recursive s3://"$s3"data_analysis --exclude "*" --include "*.saturations_reads.txt"

fi
```

Comment: You need to use a group, as in `|| { echo "whatever"; exit 1; }` if you want the `exit` to only happen if the thing on the left side of the `||` returns false.

Comment: Also, **don't use `eval`**. See [BashFAQ #48](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048) and [BashFAQ #50](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050).

Comment: ...speaking to why `'$s3'` in an `eval`ed string is dangerous, consider what happens if `s3=$'$(rm -rf ~)\'$(rm -rf ~)\''` (and note that every character in that string is valid inside a UNIX filename, so you can't safely `eval` strings with arbitrary names substituted into them)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The immediate problem here is that in `foo || bar; baz`, `baz` happens no matter what `foo`'s exit status was. In that respect, a semicolon, as a command separator, is handled in just the same way as a newline. That can be fixed with explicit grouping, as in, `foo || { bar; baz; }` -- or even more explicitly, `if foo; then bar; baz; fi`

The relevant code would be better written as:

```
# multi-line form optional, but lets you add comments after each line
snake=(
  snakemake
  --default-remote-provider S3
  --default-remote-prefix '$s3'  # FIXME: Sure you don't want "$s3" instead?
  --use-conda
  --cores 32
  --rerun-incomplete
  --printshellcmds
)
"${snake[@]}" || { echo "ERROR OCCURRED, LOOK ABOVE, EXITING" >&2; exit 1; }
```

Storing your command in an array or a function rather than a string lets you avoid `eval` and the security problems it poses; both these techniques are taught in [BashFAQ #50](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050), and the problems with `eval` are covered in detail in [BashFAQ #48](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048).

Using curly braces to put the `exit 1` inside the same group as the `echo` ensures that they happen together or not at all.

Note that `'$s3'` is correct only if you want the exact string `$s3` to be passed as the default remote prefix; if you want the *contents of the variable named s3* to be used for that, change it to `"$s3"`.

Comment: Even better, skip the variable and define a function.

Comment: I've plus-oned, but IMHO you should put more emphasis on pointing out his mistake (which is uncoditional `exit 1`) and then on improvement to his code

Comment: @InnocentBystander, good point; I've edited in a first paragraph narrowly focused there.

Comment: I like to add a function that emits an error and exits: `die () { echo "$*" >&2; exit 1; }` then the "or" clause is just `"${snake[@]}" || die "Error occurred ..."`